# Does return end a function?

Tags: solidity

```
if (true) {return 1;}
        return 0;
```

functions the same as

```
if (true) {return 1;}
        else {return 0;}
```

?

Answer (score 1):

yes

you could even drop the else

```
function doSomethin() public returns(bool a){
   if(true){
      a = true;
   }
}
```